# How to pass parameters in Scite?

Tags: scite

**Problem:**
Ran into a problem when using Scite for my ruby scripting. It will not take my parameters that I need to get the program working.

**What I discovered so far**

1: In Scite running on a Window Operating system, I have under "View -> Parameter" defined my two parameters like this.
 1. oldInventory.txt
 2. newInventory.txt
2: Saved the file
3: And then I press F5 to start it
Result: Nothing

After a little googling, I came upon this thread with a link to scite owns documentation, but after reading it I am not a wiser man.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scite-interest/kYUog8Xcuw8

Anyone encountered the same issue, and found out about what's causing the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Scite help file (avalible in "Scite menu > Help") or hosted on Internet: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDoc.html#Parameters you can read about setting Scite parameters.

I don't use Ruby, but something like this should get you going - select "Scite menu > Options > Open ruby.properties" and change the line:

```
if PLAT_WIN
    command.go.*.rb=ruby $(FileNameExt)
```

to:

```
if PLAT_WIN
    command.go.*.rb=ruby $(FileNameExt) $(1) $(2) $(3) $(4)
```